# xDebug and old wamp server with MS VC6

Tags: php, debugging, wamp, xdebug, wampserver

Can you tell me, why i don't get xDebug extension in y PHP extensions list?
Wamp>PHP>PHP extensions is not xDebug.

PHP version:

```
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC6 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.3.5
Zend API nr: 220090626
PHP API nr: 20090626
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin\php.ini
Extensions directory: c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\ext

The compiler (MS VC6) that this PHP was build with, is no longer supported. Please upgrade to a version that was built with MS VC9.
```

---

So i download: Xdebug 2.1.2, PHP 5.3 VC6 (32 bit) (MD5: adb792dc75c79384f987061f12e0934a)
Copy files to ext folder, add this lines into php.ini file:

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=1

;IP
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.auto_trace = On
xdebug.show_exception_trace = On
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.collect_vars = On
xdebug.collect_return = On
xdebug.collect_params = On
```

What's wrong?

Comment: did any body got this solution ?

Comment: I have installed the Visual C++9 but the compiler needs to upgrade. How to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine me:

```
[XDEBUG]
zend_extension="c:/path/to/your/extensions/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc6.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

The crucial part for me was that I used `zend_extension_ts` instead of `zend_extension`.

You might also want to make sure you are changing the correct version of php.ini. For command line PHP this can be obtained buy running this command:

```
php -i | findstr -i php.ini
```

Look for "Loaded Configuration File" line.